# How can I submit 3 forms in tabs by click of one button in django?

Tags: python, django, database, forms, view

I have 3 forms, first one collects user's personal information, second collects users educational information and the third one has a submit button along with checkbox.

My forms.py

```
class PersonalInfoForm(ModelForm):

    CHOICES = [('female','female'),('male','male')]

    enrolment = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)

    date_of_birth = forms.DateField(widget=DateInput)
    gender = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES,widget=forms.RadioSelect)
    class Meta:
        model = Personal_Info
        fields = [
            'enrolment',
            'first_name',
            'middle_name',
            'last_name',
            'date_of_birth',
            'gender',
            'address'
        ]

class EducationalInfoForm(ModelForm):
    username = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    class Meta:
        model = Educational_Info
        fields = [
            'ssc_marks',
            'ssc_percentage',
            'ssc_board',
            'hsc_marks',
            'hsc_percentage',
            'hsc_board',
            'college_name',
            'university',
            'semester'
        ]

class AgreeInfoForm(ModelForm):
    agree = forms.BooleanField()
    username = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    class Meta:
        model = Agree_Info
        fields = [
            'agree'
        ]
```

template named 'eligible-scholarships.html'

```
<div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div class="card">

                                    <!-- open the below card body for the from -->
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="header-title mb-3"></h4>

                                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-bordered nav-justified" role="tablist">
                                            <li class="nav-item">
                                                <a class="nav-link active" id="personal-tab-b2" data-toggle="tab" href="#personal-b2" role="tab" aria-controls="personal-b2" aria-selected="true">
                                                    <span class="d-block d-sm-none"><i class="fa fa-personal"></i></span>
                                                    <span class="d-none d-sm-block">Personal</span>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="nav-item">
                                                <a class="nav-link" id="educational-tab-b2" data-toggle="tab" href="#educational-b2" role="tab" aria-controls="educational-b2" aria-selected="false">
                                                    <span class="d-block d-sm-none"><i class="fa fa-educational"></i></span>
                                                    <span class="d-none d-sm-block">Educational</span>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="nav-item">
                                                <a class="nav-link" id="complete-tab-b2" data-toggle="tab" href="#complete-b2" role="tab" aria-controls="complete-b2" aria-selected="false">
                                                    <span class="d-block d-sm-none"><i class="fa fa-complete"></i></span>
                                                    <span class="d-none d-sm-block">Complete</span>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>

                                        </ul>
                                        <div class="tab-content">
                                            <div class="tab-pane show active" id="personal-b2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="personal-tab-b2">
                                                <div>
                                                    {{personal_form|crispy}}
                                                    <div>
                                                        <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "$('#educational-tab-b2').click()"><button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-primary">Next</button></a>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="tab-pane" id="educational-b2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="educational-tab-b2">

                                                <div>    
                                                    {{educational_form|crispy}}
                                                    <div>
                                                        <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "$('#complete-tab-b2').click()"><button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-primary">Next</button></a>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>


                                            </div>
                                            <div class="tab-pane" id="complete-b2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="complete-tab-b2">
                                                <div>
                                                    {{agree_form|crispy}}
                                                    <div>
                                                        <form name = "ajax-form" method="POST">
                                                            {% csrf_token %}
                                                            <div  class="form-group">
                                                                <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Submit" class = "btn btn-primary"/>
                                                            </div>

                                                        </form>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div> <!-- end col -->


                        </div>
```

views.py

```
def es(request):
    id = request.user.id
    print(request.user.username)
    username = request.user.username

    if not request.method == 'POST':
        print('post request',id)



        personal_form = PersonalInfoForm()
        educational_form = EducationalInfoForm()
        agree_form = AgreeInfoForm()
        args = {'personal_form':personal_form,'educational_form':educational_form,'agree_form':agree_form}
        return render(request,'eligible-scholarships.html',args)


    elif request.method == 'POST':
        id = request.user.id

        print('inside post')
        enrolment = username
        first_name = request.POST['first_name']
        middle_name = request.POST['middle_name']
        last_name = request.POST['last_name']
        date_of_birth = request.POST['date_of_birth']
        gender = request.POST['gender']
        address = request.POST['address']

        personal = Personal_Info(enrolment=enrolment,first_name=first_name,middle_name=middle_name,last_name=last_name,
                                 date_of_birth=date_of_birth,gender=gender,address=address,user_id = id)
        personal.save()


        ssc_marks = request.POST['ssc_marks']
        ssc_percentage = request.POST['ssc_percentage']
        ssc_board = request.POST['ssc_board']
        hsc_marks = request.POST['hsc_marks']
        hsc_percentage = request.POST['hsc_percentage']
        hsc_board = request.POST['hsc_board']
        college_name = request.POST['college_name']
        university = request.POST['university']
        semester = request.POST['semester']

        educational = Educational_Info(user_id = id,ssc_marks=ssc_marks,ssc_percentage=ssc_percentage,ssc_board=ssc_board,
                                            hsc_marks = hsc_marks,hsc_percentage=hsc_percentage,hsc_board=hsc_board,
                                            college_name=college_name,university=university,semester=semester)

        educational.save()
        agreeval = request.POST['agree']
        agree = Agree_Info(user_id = id,agree = agreeval)
        agree.save()
        print('all details saved successfully')
        return redirect('/es')

    return render(request,'eligible-scholarships.html',args)
```

I want to submit data from all the tabs on click of one submit button which is on the third tab. Now when I run the given code, I don't get the first_name, middle_name or other form fields. Is there any way to send all of the form data into views.py by a single submit button?

Comment: since the other tab panes doesnt have the form input thus you are not getting it. put the form before the tab from where your first form starts and end it after the last form

Comment: Yeah it worked. Thank you so much